# truffle installation on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: truffle

Trying to install truffle on Ubuntu 16.04 (on window I tried and failed). First I followed the simple instruction to install "npm install -g truffle" and later on followed this [link](http://www.techtonet.com/how-to-install-and-execute-truffle-on-an-ubuntu-16-04/) . Still not able to get through.  Please find the messages that I got on my terminal. Appreciate any help

```
root@truffle001:~# npm install -g truffle
npm WARN deprecated libp2p-ipfs@0.15.0: Renamed to libp2p-ipfs-nodejs
npm WARN deprecated jade@0.26.3: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install th                                                                      e latest version of pug instead of jade
npm WARN deprecated to-iso-string@0.0.2: to-iso-string has been deprecated, use                                                                       @segment/to-iso-string instead.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher                                                                       to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
Killed        .....] / extract:truffle: sill doParallel extract 912
```

Comment: try to update npm

Comment: npm version is 4.2.0. Would that not help? FYI node version is 7.9.0

Comment: just try npm install -g npm it may help you

Comment: I can't believe it.. It worked.. Could  you please help me understand? Now the npm version is 4.5.0. did that make the difference? Thanks .

Comment: maybe an old version of minimatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to help people who have the same problem, this issue is caused by the npm. to resolve it try to update npm :

```
 npm install -g npm
```

if it didn't work ran `npm cache clean -f`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested this recently? Latest IPFS should `npm install` cleanly on Ubuntu. Let me know if you experience something different.